# New CORS policy for Instagram public API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, instagram-api, referrer-policy

I am using these endpoints with JavaScript Ajax to get Instagram user information and posts:

[https://www.instagram.com/[username]/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%5Busername%5D/?__a=1)

[https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables={id:[user_id],first:50,after:''}](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=472f257a40c653c64c666ce877d59d2b&variables=%7Bid:%5Buser_id%5D,first:50,after:%27%27%7D)

There was not a CORS policy error before but now i'm getting that error (not every time when i refresh the page, but almost 95% times):

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.instagram.com/hannahstocking/?__a=1' from origin 'https://sitename.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Has Instagram started to block these endpoints or added a new rate limit? How can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem, if you solve the issue please share it here.

Comment: If you are getting that error message then there isn't a CORS policy **now**. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is how you set a CORS policy.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but isn't this something related to the instagram transfer policy?

Comment: Seeing same here, would love a solution.

Comment: Actually, seems IG is forcing you to be logged to view the site now?

Comment: Same happening to me. I've tried requesting jsonp - same result

Comment: AFAIU the problem is realted to Instagram blocking data center IPs. For me everything works fine on my local PC, but does not work from hosted server.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. On localhost I can fetch posts but deployed on the server the CORS error shows up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instagram has introduced a **strict-origin-when-cross-origin** policy and is only allowing the following cross origin sites:

- https://www.instagram.com
- https://*.fbcdn.net
- https://*.instagram.com
- https://*.cdninstagram.com
- https://*.facebook.com
- https://*.fbsbx.com

This leads me to believe that they are restricting websites to display the API data. The data itself is still accessible, just not directly over a website.
You would need to use a proxy or a server to resolve it