# Instagram basic display get media

Tags: angular

Hello StackOverflow Community !
Im a frontend developer and im building a website with angular to get media from public or no-public instagram accounts .I seen that token generator works only for public accounts.Is there any way to get media from privat and public instagram account ?

Comment: I reckon you take a look at their API documentation. And I highly doubt that you could access data from private profiles without proper authorization.

Comment: @AldinBradaric can you please help me to do that because im not doing well api or i have any error in my typescript? Thank you!

Comment: You could add the code you've already tried, as well as the errors you've encountered. We can take it from there then. As for Instagram's API docs, I would take a look at this here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api

Comment: @AldinBradaric thank you for the response .First of all i have create a function to get request to Instagram Api

Comment: getImagesIg(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get( 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_authentication=1&enable_fb_login=1&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A//developers.facebook.com/instagram/token_generator/oauth/%26client_id%3D514731073647678%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Duser_profile%2Cuser_media%26state%3D%257B%2522app_id%2522%3A%2522514731073647678%2522%2C%2522user_id%2522%3A%252217841452653645125%2522%2C%2522nonce%2522%3A%2522fwYToj522fFAC3sK%2522%257D');
  }

Comment: @AldinBradaric than i call this function here  instagramImages(){
    this.authservice.getImagesIg().subscribe((res:any)=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
  }

Comment: and when i click the buton that calls function it shows me these in my console /// Access to XMLHttpRequest atfrom origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @AldinBradaric and this GET https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_authentication=1&enable_fb_login=1&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A//developers.facebook.com/instagram/token_generator/oauth/%26client_id%3D514731073647678%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Duser_profile%2Cuser_media%26state%3D%257B%2522app_id%2522%3A%2522514731073647678%2522%2C%2522user_id%2522%3A%252217841452653645125%2522%2C%2522nonce%2522%3A%2522fwYToj522fFAC3sK%2522%257D net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: You can edit your initial post, no need to post multiple comments :-)

Comment: As for your CORS issue, it seems that Instagram is applying a string origin check, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66336314/new-cors-policy-for-instagram-public-api

Comment: @AldinBradaric in my facebook developer app i have the domain with https ,i dont understand where the problem ,in api or in my domain address in my app ,because when you click the api i can access instagram auth window ,but it doesnt work in website when i click the button

Comment: @AldinBradaric can you help me please,because im still trying but nothing yet